# ZeroMQ PGM Multicast and encryption?

Tags: zeromq

I want to send a boot image to a cluster of compute nodes using ZeroMQ PGM protocols. It would be nice it the image is send encrypted or at least signed to prevent tampering mid transport.

Can I use Curve with ZeroMQ PGM protocol?

Answer (score 0):

> To provide security over other transports that fit the one-to-one model (it will not work over multicast).

https://github.com/zeromq/libcurve

seems to be not possible, but i'm also looking for something like this.